# Change front size in expression in SSRS

Tags: html, reporting-services

I've expression in ssrs textbox:

```
="<ul><li><a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>Shopping</a></li><li>text</li><li>text</li></ul>"
```

How can I increase the font in the list?

Comment: Reporting Services has font properties built in, you don't need HTML.

Comment: To add to above, you can't modify style directly in the tags, ex: style='font-size:200%'. SSRS only supports a very limited amount of html in their reports.